# CakePHP, How do I retrieve data from multiple tables for a landing Page?

Tags: cakephp, model-view-controller

I'm fairly new to cake and went trough the tutorials and a beginner book for Cake that my university offered.

My problem is basically that I want to create a landing page for my WebApp which essentially needs to get data from tables that are in no association to each other. Think of something like retrieving the weather for today and from another table the latest news. Now obviously there is a controller/model/view for the weather and for the news. But how do I create a controller/model/view for this now? Do I just make a controller "overview", route there, have no model and get the data in the index function of the "overview" controller via requestAction from the other 2 controllers? I'm not sure how the correct way to do this is in Cake/MVC. Also this "Overview" Controller obviously would not have a corresponding table in the database, it just draws data from multiple others.

Best Regards,
Alex.

Comment: See https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/cells.html

Comment: @burzum so I'd basically use a cell for each table i want to use on my overview page. But I'd still need to make an empty controller to even get a view page in which i can use the cells, right?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily use CakePHP loadModel method in your controller [Here](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#loading-additional-models) you will find more information.

```
$this->loadModel('ModelName');
```

Or if your models are associated with other table you can also use `$this->ModelName->find()->contain(['Model1, Model2'])` For more information visit [Here](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#namespace-Cake%5CORM)

Hope this information will help you

Thank you.